# VS Code Format Code Keyboard Shortcut messes up C# spaces

Tags: c#, format, visual-studio-code

I have been trying to figure this one out. I have my workspace settings set as follows:

```
{
    "files.trimTrailingWhitespace": true,
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 1000,
    "files.exclude": {
      "**/.git": true,
      "**/.DS_Store": true,
      // hide js when typscript file present
      "**/*.js": {"when": "$(basename).ts"}
    },
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.referenceInfos": false,
    "editor.wrappingColumn": 0,
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false
}
```

When i go to a new line in a C# file it auto indents 2 spaces. But when I perform the format code keyboard shortcut (SHIFT+ALT+F on windows) it indents the code with what looks like 4 spaces for the entire file. There is a lot of settings so I could have missed the one I need to set for auto format to work correctly. How can I get the auto format to make everything 2 spaces? To confirm my settings, the bottom of the editor and says **Spaces:2**. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem an its olny happening with .cs files with other extensions is working fine.

Comment: i think this has been submitted as an issue, i remember reading it a while back, but could not find the github post.